# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError MEAN Stack

Tags: angular

So when I press edit a `contract` I'm getting all data except the two dates and also getting this error

**ERROR**

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'value: 1/1/1970'.
>
> Current value: 'value: '.
>
> at viewDebugError (core.js:7299)
>
> at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:7287)
>
> at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:7389)
>
> at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:10249)
>
> at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:10236)
>
> at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:10839)
>
> at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:10767)
>
> at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (EditComponent.html:16)
>
> at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:10756)
>
> at checkNoChangesView (core.js:10135)

Im using a MEAN stack and using the Angular's Material Module. Also using FormBuilder and FormGroup

```
    ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params.id;
      this.contractService.getContractById(this.id).subscribe(res => {
        this.contract = res;
        this.updateForm.get('titulliProkurimit').setValue(this.contract.titulliProkurimit);
        this.updateForm.get('dataPublikimit').setValue(this.contract.dataPublikimit);
        this.updateForm.get('dataNenshkrimit').setValue(this.contract.dataNenshkrimit);
        this.updateForm.get('vleraFillestare').setValue(this.contract.vleraFillestare);
        this.updateForm.get('vleraFinale').setValue(this.contract.vleraFinale);
        this.updateForm.get('drejtoria').setValue(this.contract.drejtoria);
      });
    });
  }



updateContract(titulliProkurimit, dataPublikimit, dataNenshkrimit, vleraFillestare, vleraFinale, drejtoria) {
    this.contractService.updateContract(this.id, titulliProkurimit, dataPublikimit, dataNenshkrimit, vleraFillestare, vleraFinale, drejtoria).subscribe(() => {
      this.snackBar.open('Contract Updated Successfully!', 'OK', {
        duration: 3000
      });
      this.router.navigate(['/contracts']);
    });
  }
```

These are the two values that are not showing on the updating form

```
 <mat-form-field class='field-full-width'>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder='Publication Date' formControlName='dataPublikimit'
      [value]="dataPublikimit.value" #dataPublikimit>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class='
      field-full-width'>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder='Assignment Date' formControlName='dataNenshkrimit'
      [value]="dataNenshkrimit.value" #dataNenshkrimit>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Which property is set to `value: 1/1/1970`? Can you please edit your question to include anywhere that property is being set?

Comment: When using reactive forms and setValue, you shouldn't also be binding to the 'value' property. Try removing those bindings and see if that helps.

Comment: @DeborahK I removed the [value] on both and it worked , thanks a lot.
Now I just have to fix the contract dates showing like this "2018-10-09T22:00:00.000Z" and make them look more readable.
Thank you again.